# Rails database table changed name, but index in another table refers to old name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I changed a table name from "Addresses" to "Locations". Here are the two models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :people, through: :years 

class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :person
```

I made the change by a `rename_table :addresses, :locations` migration and changed names of folders, files and all references in the relevant controllers and views. Most everything seems OK except the Years database still has a column `address_id` in the years table. It obviously needs to be `location_id`. Can I just migrate the change.? Will the links to the newly named database be preserved? I've backed up the database and made a spreadsheet copy of the Years output.

An prechange version of the project is at https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5/src. I'm reluctant to merge the changes into master until I have it sorted out.

Thanks for suggestions.

PS. I don't recommend changing a table name, but I had a field named address in the addresses table and wanted to get rid of that confusion. Needless to say, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the thing you're looking for is to simply rename the column in the `Years` table:

```
rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
```

Perhaps

```
rename_column :years, :address_id, :location_id
```

After the migration the years table will have a location_id column that will have the same values as you had in there before.

EDIT: it is not required to have any column any particular name (though it is almost always easier if your app does thing the "rails way). You can, for example, define the Years model to reference the Location model via a column that has an "incorrect" name.

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, foreign_key: :address_id, primary_key: :id
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but wanted some assurance that I wasn't falling into a trap. Seems to work well. I just thought the database might have some structure I was missing.